# How to print all destination ports and source ports in the PCAP file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, packets, pyshark

```
import pyshark
pkts = pyshark.FileCapture("test.pcap")


for p in pkts:
      print
```

I am trying to print all destination ports and source ports in the PCAP file. How could I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import pyshark

pkts = pyshark.FileCapture('cap.pcap')

for p in pkts:
    if hasattr(p, 'tcp'):
        print(p.tcp.srcport + ' -- ' + p.tcp.dstport)
    if hasattr(p, 'udp'):
        print(p.udp.srcport + ' -- ' + p.udp.dstport)
```